# How to set Two inputs on same row in react native ?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-universal

Hey I want to set two textInputs on same line , named
Expiration date and CVV in android simulator.

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
<Text style={styles.label}style= {{width : 100}}>Expiration date</Text>
    <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputdate} />  
    </View>

      <Text style={styles.label}>CVV</Text>
   <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
      <TextInput  style={styles.inputcvv } maxLength={17} />
  </View>
```

Here it is including  CSS for both textInputs 
\

```
inputWrap: {
             borderColor: '#cccccc',
             borderBottomWidth: 1,
             marginBottom: 10,
   },
     inputdate: {
        fontSize: 14,
        marginBottom : -12,
        color: '#6a4595',
      },
      inputcvv: {
        fontSize: 14,
        marginBottom : -12,
        color: '#6a4595',
      },
```

Please let me know how can i set this on same line.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With React Native you need to use **Flexbox** for laying out your components. Check out the [Flexbox docs here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html).

You want to do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>Expiration date</Text>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputdate} />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>CVV</Text>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputcvv} maxLength={17} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  inputWrap: {
    flex: 1,
    borderColor: "#cccccc",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  inputdate: {
    fontSize: 14,
    marginBottom: -12,
    color: "#6a4595"
  },
  inputcvv: {
    fontSize: 14,
    marginBottom: -12,
    color: "#6a4595"
  }
});
```

The important part here is the `flexDirection: "row"` on the `<View style={styles.row}>` element and the `flex: 1` on the `<View style={styles.inputWrap}>` elements.

You can edit and run this snippet with Snack (Expo):

https://snack.expo.io/rySUxTKuZ

Answer (score 4):

[image: UI breakup]

Divide your overall view as shown in figure.

```
    export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.outerContainer}>
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.fieldName}>
            Name1
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
            <TextInput />
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.fieldName}>
            Name2
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
            <TextInput />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
      },
      innerContainer: {
        flex: 0.5,
        flexDirection: 'row'
      },
      fieldName: {
        flex: 1,
      },
      textInputContainer: {
        flex: 3,
      },
    });
```

Give margins wherever necessary.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

you can try something like this

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    height:100
  }}>
    <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
      <Text style={styles.label} >Expiration date</Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.inputDate} />
    </View>

    <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>CVV</Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.inputCvv} maxLength={17} />
    </View>
  </View>
 );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  label: {
  flex: 1,
  fontWeight: 'bold'
},
inputWrap: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'space-between',
  flexDirection: 'column'
},
inputDate: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#108c96',
},
inputCvv: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#6fa511',

}
});
```